# PostSharp - Using different versions by TFS branches looks not possible

Tags: postsharp

Our project was using until now the version 3.0.28 of PostSharp Express (NuGet package + VS extension). 
We would like to migrate our solution to the last version of PostSharp (4.1.*) on our current dev branch. So we updated NuGet package and installed the corresponding Visual Studio extension on each developer computer. This migration has been done without any problem.

Unfortunately, since this migration, our developers can't work on our Release & ServicePack branches which are staying on 3.0.28 PostSharp version. They have the following error during compilation :

```
Error   3   The assembly 'MyDll.dll' uses non-licensed features (Basic Features). Please visit http://www.postsharp.net/purchase to acquire a license of PostSharp. 
Error   4   Information regarding the previous message: the installed user license is: "Version=2, LicenseId=0, LicenseType=13, Product=PostSharp30".
```

Do you know if there is any possibility to work with different PostSharp versions on the same VS environment?

Thanks in advance for your help!

ps : sorry for my clumsy English :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PostSharp Express license format has been changed at some point after 3.0.28 release and the new license keys are not recognizable by older PostSharp versions.

To solve the issue you can upgrade your service branches to the latest build of PostSharp 3.0 or 3.1.